# Split Commandline Output Via Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get specific lsblk output cell? (python will be used on Ubuntu).
I want to get `285M` value for `sda1 x FSAVAIL` cell and `""` value for empty `sda x FSAVAIL` cell.

```
NAME   KNAME FSAVAIL FSUSED PKNAME
sda    sda                  
├─sda1 sda1     285M   148K sda
├─sda2 sda2                 sda
└─sda3 sda3      87G   410G sda
sr0    sr0
```

I have tried getting every row data and splitting it but it does not have same width for all cells (e.g. width of the `KNAME` column is smaller than `FSAVAIL` column).

```
a1 = (subprocess.check_output("lsblk -o NAME,KNAME,FSAVAIL,FSUSED,PKNAME", shell=True).strip()).decode()
a2 = a1.split("\n")
```

Comment: Try the `-J` argument to `lsblk` to get the output in easy to parse JSON.

Comment: You can get what you want by: `lsblk /dev/sda1 -p FSAVAIL -n`

Comment: @Nathan Xabedi, FSAVAIL is not reconized. It gives output as FSAVAIL is not used.

Comment: He mixed up `-p` and `-o`.

Comment: @Klaus D. (```-J```) @Nathan Xabedi (```lsblk /dev/sda1 -o FSAVAIL -n```), your comments are useful, thanks. They are all comments and there is no answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the method suggested by [@Klaus D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d):

```py
import json
import subprocess

raw_data = subprocess.check_output("cat data.json", shell=True).decode().strip()
data = json.loads(raw_data)
FSAVAIL = data.get("blockdevices")[0].get("children")[0].get("fsavail")
```

Using the method suggested by [@Nathan Xabedi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8260266/nathan-xabedi):

```py
import subprocess
FSAVAIL = subprocess.check_output("lsblk /dev/sda1 -o FSAVAIL -n", shell=True).decode().strip()
```